# How to change the intrinsic content size through its priority

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want the second label (`subview2`) to stay intact and have the first label (`subview1`) shrink as the size of the container view decreases in size, but the second label is still shrink no matter how I adjust the priority:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 300)))
let subview1 = UILabel()
subview1.text = "Hello"
subview1.backgroundColor = .red
containerView.addSubview(subview1)
subview1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let subview2 = UILabel()
subview2.text = "Hello"
subview2.backgroundColor = .cyan
containerView.addSubview(subview2)
subview2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let views: [String: Any] = ["subview1": subview1, "subview2": subview2]
let con1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(20)-[subview1]", metrics: nil, views: views)
let con2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(20)-[subview2]", metrics: nil, views: views)
let con3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(30)-[subview1]", metrics: nil, views: views)
let con4 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[subview2]-(30)-|", metrics: nil, views: views)
let con5 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[subview1(>=100)]-(>=30)-[subview2(>=100)]", metrics: nil, views: views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(con1 + con2 + con3 + con4 + con5)

subview1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
subview2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

[image]

I've tried increasing the priority of `subview2` manually, but still didn't work:

```swift
let priority1 = subview2.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .horizontal)
print(priority1) // 750
let priority2 = subview2.contentCompressionResistancePriority(for: .horizontal)
print(priority2) // 750
subview2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(priority2 + 100, for: .horizontal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFL (Visual Format Language) is very out-dated and limited. I strongly suggest you switch to more modern (and more flexible) syntax.

That said, the problem is with this line:

```
let con5 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: 
            "H:[subview1(>=100)]-(>=30)-[subview2(>=100)]", metrics: nil, views: views)
```

Your code is saying:

- `subview1` width ***must be*** greater-than-or-equal-to `100`
- `subview2` width ***must be*** greater-than-or-equal-to `100`

so, the `setContentCompressionResistancePriority` lines do nothing. You've already said "these are the **required** minimum widths."

If you change that line to:

```
let con5 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:
            "H:[subview1]-(>=30)-[subview2]", metrics: nil, views: views)
```

you should get your desired result.

Here, though, is your code using more modern constraint syntax -- you may find it much more logical and easier to understand:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    // both labels 20-pts from containerView Top
    subview1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
    subview2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),

    // left label Leading 30-pts from containerView Leading
    subview1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),

    // right label Trailing 30-pts from containerView Trailing
    subview2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0),

    // right label Leading at least 30-pts from left label Trailing
    subview2.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: subview1.trailingAnchor, constant: 30.0),

])

// don't do any of this...
//let views: [String: Any] = ["subview1": subview1, "subview2": subview2]
//let con1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(20)-[subview1]", metrics: nil, views: views)
//let con2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(20)-[subview2]", metrics: nil, views: views)
//let con3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(30)-[subview1]", metrics: nil, views: views)
//let con4 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[subview2]-(30)-|", metrics: nil, views: views)
//let con5 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[subview1]-(>=30)-[subview2]", metrics: nil, views: views)
//NSLayoutConstraint.activate(con1 + con2 + con3 + con4 + con5)
```

---

**Edit** *- to answer comment...*

If you want the widths of your labels to each be `>= 100`, but allow them to compress (left-label compresses first), you need to add width constraints with Priority of less-than `.required`:

```
// both labels should have a width of >= 100
let leftWidth = subview1.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100.0)
let rightWidth = subview2.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100.0)

// set the Priority on the width constraints to less than required
//  to allow auto-layout to break that constraint if needed
leftWidth.priority = .defaultHigh
rightWidth.priority = .defaultHigh

// activate the width constraints
leftWidth.isActive = true
rightWidth.isActive = true

// tell leftLabel to compress before rightLabel
subview1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
subview2.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with using the modern Autolayout. My approach was more of an academic one to learn about the nature of priorities and the intrinsic content size and how changing them effects the layout. Without entirely getting rid of the width constant, how would you specify the subviews to "have a certain width but only decrease in size when the container gets smaller than the given width"? So let's say I want 100 points for each views initially and have the container's priority overpower that if the subviews.